# I got a import error: no module named cv2

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I already installed python3.5, opencv3.3.0, and numpy20.2.4 on my raspberry pi refer to https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/09/04/raspbian-stretch-install-opencv-3-python-on-your-raspberry-pi/. But once I try running. It display import error: no module named cv2. Someone can help. I am new. Thank you

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap = set(3,640) #set Width
cap = set(4,480) #set Height

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame =  cv2.flip(frame, -1) # flip camera vertically
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    cv2.imshow ('frame',frame)
    cv2.imshow ('gray',gray)
    
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) &0xff
    if k == 27: #press  ESC to exit
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Face_recognition.py", line 2, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: No module named cv2
```

Comment: what is the output of `python --version` cmd?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you tried any of the [many](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=No+module+named+cv2) questions about the same error?

Comment: Did you have `virtualenv` configured? if so, make sure that your code editor interpreter using this specific environment.